# setting focus on Proxy vue3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I am new to vue3 and working with proxies, and am running into an issues setting focus on a proxy that is passed into my component  as a prop.

In the parent component I have:

```
<Button ref="elementToFocus" @click="handleClickEvent"/>
   
<Modal :isOpen="toggleOpen" :returnFocus="$refs['elementToFocus']" @close="toggleOpen">
```

And in that Modal component I am accessing `elementToFocus` in a method that handles closing it:

```
handleClose() {
            this.$emit('close');
            if( this.returnFocus ) {
              this.returnFocus.focus();
            }
        }
```

However, I keep getting the error `TypeError: this.returnFocus.focus is not a function`, I think because `this.returnFocus` is a Proxy. Do I need to access that element via vanilla JS instead? I'm not if this is an intended use for a proxy. Any help would be much appreciated!